# The strange behavior of `delete-after` attribute of dynamic shovel

Tags: rabbitmq, messagebroker, rabbitmq-shovel

I was exploring the shovel plugin for moving the messages from source to temporary queues as a part of a bigger use case. I was creating the dynamic shovel for each queue to move the messages to the temporary queue and delete the dynamic shovel using the attribute **"delete-after": "queue-length"**. I have seen in the RabbitMQ Management console(Admin->Shovel status) that the dynamic shovel got deleted successfully, but the source/temporary queues' state was running.

*But the issue was that when new messages were coming to the source queues, they were automatically moving to the temporary queues even though there was no consumer of the source queue.*

Note:

1. Source and temporary both queues are durable.
2. Messages are persistent (Delivery mode: 2)
3. The said operation was performed parallelly as there are hundreds of queues. I was creating dynamic shovel for each queue and delete them.

[image: Queue status after deleting dynamic shovel]
While I'm removing the dynamic shovel using the DELETE HTTP API instead of the above approach, it's working perfectly. I want to avoid making an extra HTTP call as the no of source queues are hundreds.

Comment: It is observed in RabbitMQ v3.8.3, but it's working well with RabbitMQ v3.7.x

Answer (score 0):

**delete-after** attribute has been deprecated and renamed with **src-delete-after** a long back. RMQ v3.7.x has the support of delete-after attribute but it was removed in v3.8.x(up to 3). Then it was brought back in v3.8.4

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-shovel/issues/72

Thanks to [Michael](https://github.com/michaelklishin)